# My iPhone5 App shows as it would be only a 3.5'' App on 4'' screens, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios-simulator, iphone-5

i just submitted an update of my App iJobber. I have no iPhone 5 so i only tried it out with the simulator and everything seemed to look good on new iPhones.

But after submitting the App and downloading it on a friends iPhone 5, it only shows the 3,5'' UI and not the special one for the bigger screen.

Whats happening? What can be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to trigger the slightly taller "iPhone 5" mode on device, you need to include a `Default-568h@2x.png` file.

Comment: aah thanks, i didn't do that.
and i wonder why the simulator shows the 4'' version but not real devices.